# 3D plots don't show box or axes in 11.3 on Linux

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am using Mathematica 11.3 Student Edition on Linux (Ubuntu). When I make a 3D plot using `Plot3D` or `ParametricPlot3D` or any other 3D plotting function, I don't see the bounding box or axes no matter what options I give.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t/2, Cos[\[Pi] t], Sin[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 6}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

This doesn't happen when I make 2D plots.

Edit: In response to a comment, here's what I get for

```
AssociationMap[
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #}] &, {"Graphics3D", 
  "Graphics3DAxes", "Graphics3DTicks", "Graphics3DBox"}]
```

The result is:

```
<|"Graphics3D" -> {CellMargins -> {{4, Inherited}, {Inherited, 
      Inherited}}, CellGroupingRules -> "GraphicsGrouping", 
   StripStyleOnPaste -> False, PageBreakWithin -> False, 
   GeneratedCell -> True, CellAutoOverwrite -> True, 
   ShowCellLabel -> False, 
   DefaultFormatType -> DefaultOutputFormatType, 
   ContextMenu -> {MenuItem["Cu&t Graphics Selection", "Cut"], 
     MenuItem["&Copy Graphics Selection", "Copy"], 
     MenuItem["&Paste into Graphic", FrontEnd`Paste[After]], 
     Delimiter, 
     MenuItem["&Drawing Tools", 
      FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookOpen[
         FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["DrawingTools.nb", 
          "PrivatePathsSystemResources"]]}]], 
     MenuItem["&Get Coordinates", 
      FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetCoordinates"]]], 
     Delimiter, MenuItem["G&roup", "Group"], 
     MenuItem["&Ungroup", "Ungroup"], Delimiter, 
     MenuItem["Move to &Front", "MoveToFront"], 
     MenuItem["Move to &Back", "MoveToBack"], 
     MenuItem["Move For&ward", "MoveForward"], 
     MenuItem["Move Bac&kward", "MoveBackward"]}, 
   "AutoStyleOptionsHighlightMisspelledWords" -> False, 
   LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage", FormatType -> StandardForm, 
   ShowStringCharacters -> False, NumberMarks -> False, 
   CounterIncrements -> "Graphics", 
   ImageMargins -> {{43, Inherited}, {Inherited, 0}}, 
   Arrowheads -> 0.04, Dashing -> None, CapForm -> "Round", 
   JoinForm -> "Round", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], LineOpacity -> 1, 
   EdgeColor -> GrayLevel[0], EdgeOpacity -> 1, 
   EdgeThickness -> Absolute[0.5], EdgeDashing -> None, 
   EdgeCapForm -> "Round", EdgeJoinForm -> "Round", 
   FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[1], 
   Notebook$$13$561562`FrontFaceGlowColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
   FrontFaceSpecularColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
   FrontFaceSpecularExponent -> 1.5, BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[1], 
   Notebook$$13$561562`BackFaceGlowColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
   BackFaceSpecularColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
   BackFaceSpecularExponent -> 1.5, FrontFaceOpacity -> 1, 
   BackFaceOpacity -> 1, GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
   PointSize -> Absolute[3], Thickness -> Absolute[0.5], Opacity -> 1,
    DrawEdges -> True, DrawFrontFaces -> True, DrawBackFaces -> True, 
   StyleMenuListing -> None, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 10, 
   FontWeight -> "Plain", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
   FontOpacity -> 1}, 
 "Graphics3DAxes" -> {LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], 
   Thickness -> Absolute[0.5]}, 
 "Graphics3DTicks" -> {ScriptLevel -> 1, LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.4]},
  "Graphics3DBox" -> {LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], 
   FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], 
   GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], Thickness -> Absolute[0.5], 
   FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.4]}|>
```

[image: ParametricPlot3D with "Boxed -> True" and "Axes -> True" options, but no box or axes showing]

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in 11.1.1, 11.2 or 11.3. Which version exactly are you using, and on which Operating System? Also, can you add the output of `AssociationMap[CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #}] &, {"Graphics3D", "Graphics3DAxes", "Graphics3DTicks", "Graphics3DBox"}]` to your question?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 11.3, Student edition, on Linux

Comment: I just checked on a different machine and it turns out that the problem doesn't happen in MacOS with 11.2

Comment: Thanks for this!